# Prevent user from going back on browser if already logged in (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I would like to refresh the current page (home) when the user tries to go back via browser, after logged in.

What's the best way to solve this? Any suggestions?

I was trying to do something like this inside index.tsx:

```
if (id) {
    const rollback = history.goBack();
    if (rollback) {
        history.push('/');
    }
}
```

Obs: In this case, '/' is my home page, and i can't apply the logic above because "An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness".

Sorry for anything i'm still new at react and trying to learn.

Don't know if i could do something inside my router, here it is anyway:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from '../utils/history';

import LoadingPage from '../components/organisms/LoadingPage';

const DownloadExams = lazy(() => import('../pages/private/DownloadExams'));
const Home = lazy(() => import('../pages/private/Home'));
const ProfileSelector = lazy(() => import('../pages/private/ProfileSelector'));

const AppRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Suspense fallback={<LoadingPage />}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path={'/baixar-exames'} component={DownloadExams} />
                    <Route exact path={'/profile'} component={ProfileSelector} />
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default AppRoutes;
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

User logIn time you can store a `token` or `flag` and store it in `localStorage`. After that, you can check if the user login so redirects to the page. You can also create some `HOC` for the same.

Example :

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("token");

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location,
                },
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Example Usage :

`<ProtectedRoute path="/home" exact component={Home} />`

This will redirect the user to `/home` after login.